# how to do nested query in Parse API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

In the user object, there's an array of features:

skills: {"piano:10", "singing:5", ....};

then I want to select users with skills of 'piano', how can I do it?
it won't be an exact match but it has the same rule: starting with the string 'piano'

thanks!

i'm trying to query by:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.startsWith('skills', skill);
```

but that doesn't work. i tried to use contain, doesn't work either...
any advice will be highly appreciated!

Comment: where's the `user` array/object sample to loop through? Snippet shown isn't enough to map new data

Comment: `$.map` is perfect for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

To extract a subset from an array, I find reduce to be really convenient. This is how I would do it:

```
var arr = [{piano:3, guitar:8, name: 'benny'}, {drums:4, name: 'anna'}];

arr.reduce(function (ack, current) {
    if (current.hasOwnProperty('piano')) {
        ack.push(current);
    }
    return ack;
}, []);

// Result: [{piano:3, guitar:8, name: 'benny'}];
```